# Transforming Array Orientation

Tags: php, arrays, dimension

Can anyone help me transforming an array. 
It's actually a query result from a MySQL database.

**Existing:**

```
(
[ITEM] => Array
        (
            [0] => PRODUCT A
            [1] => PRODUCT B
            [2] => PRODUCT C

        )

[REFERENCE] => Array
        (
            [0] => 107AW3
            [1] => 204RS67O
            [2] => 25GTR56

        )
```

**Wanted:**

```
 (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ITEM] => Product A
            [REFERENCE] => 107AW3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ITEM] => Product B
            [REFERENCE] => 204RS67O
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ITEM] => Product C
            [REFERENCE] => 25GTR56
        )
```

What can I do to transform the array into the wanted one? 
A glance of info, it is actually a query from MySQL:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $item_array[] = $row["item"];
        $reference_array[] = $row["reference"];  
    }
} 

table_content = array('ITEM'=>$item_array,
                      'REFERENCE'=>$reference_array);

echo '<pre>'; print_r($table_content); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: just change the structure inside the while block, `$table_content[] = $row`

Answer (score 2):

You can use only one array:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          $item_array[] = [
             'ITEM' => $row["item"],
             'REFERENCE' => $row["reference"],
          ];
      }
    }
```

Comment: Probably even just `$item_array[] = $row`, because, come on, does the capitalisation really matter…?

Comment: If anyone does not want to write all the keys individually, you can use `$item_array[] = array_change_key_case($row, CASE_UPPER);` to transform the keys to upper case. For as little as two keys this would yet be less readable and slower than just writing them yourself.

Comment: If anyone needs just a subset of fields from `$row` and does not want to write each key individually, you can make a list of keys, like `$keyWhitelist = array_flip(['item', 'reference']);` and use `$item_array[] = array_intersect_key($row, $keyWhitelist);` to extract only those keys. Yet for two keys that would be an overkill and slower than just extracting them individually.

Comment: Thanks a lot Litvak and others, what a  great solution.